# handling "Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSNumber' "

Tags: swift

I have a json that gets turned to a dictionary object. When dumped you can see the following is returned

```
▿ (2 elements)
  - key: "LivingArea"
  - value: NULL #2
    - super: NSString
      - super: NSObject
```

assume userDict is my dictionary object

```
let LivingArea = userDict?["LivingArea"] as? Int
```

returns: Optional(5)

but i need it unwrapped so I try

```
let LivingArea = userDict?["LivingArea"] as! Int
```

This makes app crash with the following:
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x111601d60) to 'NSNumber' (0x110c0e4a8).

How do I get the value of LivingArea unwrapped. Why does it not behave as Int?
this is an example of the json

```
["District": 4, "Napa": 43, "LivingArea": 2, "CityName": LA, "CityCode": 1103]
```

thank you

Comment: The error clearly says that the value is a `string` rather than a `(NS)number`. And please name variables with a starting lowercase letter.

Comment: It seems that not all of the entries in your JSON have a numeric value for `LivingArea`. You should keep the variable as an optional and unwrap it when required. Don't force unwrap or you will get a crash. Another option is to set a default of 0 using `let livingArea = userDict?["LivingArea"] as? Int ?? 0`

Comment: @AshokKumarReddyPolu I get the following:  cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'

Comment: Yes, ignore that suggestion. It still has a force unwrap so it will crash on missing values

Comment: @Paulw11 did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that not all of the entries in your JSON have a numeric value for LivingArea.

One option is to keep the variable as an optional and unwrap it when required. Don't force unwrap or you will get a crash when the value is missing or no an integer.

You should code defensively, especiallly when dealing with data from an external source.

Another option is to set a default of 0 using

```
let livingArea = userDict?["LivingArea"] as? Int ?? 0
```